# "Conflict with something" VS "be held at the same time frame"

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

I wonder if the following two sentences mean the same in the context below. (If they do not please let me know about the reason):

I need to chose between the math and the science classes......

a. They **conflict with each other**. 
b. They **are held at the same time frame**.

To me, they mean the same here, but I doubt if natives think the same as me.

Also, I need to know whether the use of the word "frame" at the structure "at the same time **frame**" is optional or that is a fixed term in this sense?

Comment: b. Should read, "They are held at the same time." No "frame".

Comment: (b) is not idiomatic. You could say _they are timetabled for the same period_, or _they clash with one another_ (clash = inconveniently occur at the same time).

Comment: Well, therefore @KateBunting we can say: "**these two classes are held at the same time**" which means the same as "**these two classes conflict / clash with each other.**" Right?

Comment: Well, yes, we can!